# fetch data from the curl command in some variable in python

Tags: python, json, rasa-nlu

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
Accept: application/json
Content-Type:application/json
Content-Length: 43

{  "me": "username",  "something": 1465057519  }
```

As a server, if I want to fetch the values of "me" and "something" in any variable so that I will convert it to json format. How will I get it ? Like form some other machine if i am getting that curl request and everytime it have different value for "me" or some other key name. How will I fetch it to parse it and give the response back from where the curl command has come?

Comment: Use `json.loads()` on the request body.

Comment: I am new to python and json would you please elaborate by giving one example on how to do that.

Comment: I solved my problem.Thanku so much for your help.I know how to ask and what to ask